# Getting undefined when calling the function

Tags: javascript

I have this function which parses the JSON. I am getting undefined when I am calling it in a .live function.

Here is the function that I have created,

```
function getAbc() {
                    var details;
                    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
                    $.ajax({
                        url : '/index.php/data',
                        type : 'GET',
                        data : 'persons[]=' + id,
                        success : function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                            details = JSON.parse(data);
                        },
                    });
                    return details;
                }
```

I am simply calling like this, getAbc(). And is there any way that I can access details variable in the function?

Comment: `$ajax` has a callback for a reason. It's asynchronous.

Comment: Also use `getAbc.call(this)` instead of `getAbc()` to bind the context from the calling function to `getAbc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use continuation passing style. The `$.ajax` is async in nature.

```
function getAbc(callback) {
    var details;
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({
       url : '/index.php/data',
       type : 'GET',
       data : 'persons[]=' + id,
       success : function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
           details = JSON.parse(data);
           callback(details);
       }
    });
}

function getAbc(function (details) {
    console.log(details);
});
```

Comment: Can I use something like console.log(getAbc().details)?

Comment: @user1890338 - You can put the logic that processes details in the second function.  Then you would call the first function directly.  (I believe the functions are supposed to have different names, but I could be wrong - I'm far from a JavaScript expert.  If that's the case, I would rename the second function _processDetails()_ for clarity.)

Comment: I have a .live function. I want to use it in that one

Answer (score 1):

That's because `ajax` happens *asynchronously*.  That means `getAbc` returns *before* `success` is invoked, because the request goes over the wire.  You need to use `details` in the `success` callback, not after the `getAbc` method returns.  Alternatively, in `success` call another method that uses details, and pass `details` to that method.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the way AJAX works.

AJAX requests are asynchronous, which means they do not return immediately.

When you make an AJAX call, a request is made that completes at an unknown time.

You can use a callback function to handle the results.

A callback function is a function that gets executed **AFTER** the response is received from the AJAX request.

You can specify a callback function and pass it to your AJAX call.